# MATLAB way for representing and operating on an array of matrices

Tags: performance, matlab, for-loop, matrix, vectorization

I'm writing a program that calculates the time evolution of a two qubit density matrix (that is a `4 x 4` matrix) and I would like to apply certain functions to the density matrix at each time step. For example, a typical function would be `trace(rho^2)` where `rho` is the density matrix at a particular time.

In Mathematica I can easily achieve this by creating a list of matrices and using `Map` to apply the  desired function to each matrix. In MATLAB, it seemed obvious to me to implement my time evolution function so that it returns a `4 x 4 x NSTEPS` array, but then the only way that came to my mind for applying the function to each 4 x 4 matrix was a `for` loop, like

```
for i = 1:size(rho,3)
   p(i) = real(trace(rho(:,:,i)^2));
end
```

Since I've been taught to avoid `for` loops as much as possible in MATLAB, what is the MATLAB way (or the most efficient way) of doing such thing?

Comment: You've been taught wrong.  (1) The old rule of thumb that loops are slower than vectorised operations is just that, an old rule of thumb.  Recent releases of Matlab have made it moot.  (2) If you can express what you want to do with loops, use loops.  Only later, if the performance is unacceptable (something you don't even hint at being the case) consider optimisations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Version 1**

```
p = squeeze(sum(sum(bsxfun(@times,rho,permute(rho,[2 1 3])))))
```

**Version 2**

```
p = sum(reshape(bsxfun(@times,rho,permute(rho,[2 1 3])),[],size(rho,3)))
```

**Benchmarking Code**

```
%%// Original for-loop code
tic
for k = 1:10
    p = zeros(size(rho,3),1);
    for i = 1:size(rho,3)
        p(i) = real(trace(rho(:,:,i)^2));
    end
end
toc
clear p

%%// Version 1
tic
for k = 1:10
    p = squeeze(sum(sum(bsxfun(@times,rho,permute(rho,[2 1 3])))));
end
toc
clear p

%%// Version 2
tic
for k = 1:10
    p = sum(reshape(bsxfun(@times,rho,permute(rho,[2 1 3])),[],size(rho,3)));
end
toc
```

**Benchmarking Results**

**With `rho` as `50x50x50`**

```
Elapsed time is 0.061841 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.008360 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.004700 seconds.
```

**With `rho` as `200x200x50`**

```
Elapsed time is 0.421595 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.140892 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.135933 seconds.
```

**With `rho` as `500x500x50`**

```
Elapsed time is 4.973693 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.899126 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.894188 seconds.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The code is great, but it is specific for the `trace(rho^2)` function. I was wondering whether there is a vectorized syntax that I can apply to map a generic function to each of the matrices that I store in my array.

Comment: @Pincopallino What other functions do you intend to use?

Comment: I have some functions that return a value when applied to a 4x4 matrix. An example is Negativity, which is more complicated, as it involves eigenvalues and partial transposition (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negativity_(quantum_mechanics) for the definition). Anyway, my question was about the best MATLAB practice to map a generic function to an array of matrices (or any other structure that is more appropriate)

Comment: I prefer using `bsxfun` for vectorization among other methods. Look into it's documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html). As the first paramter to it, you can specify function names. If you see any function there that matches with or sounds close to what you intend to implement, then yes `bsxfun` would be one approach.

Comment: @Pincopallino In general `bsxfun` will be a very fast way to get what you want, and a loop will be a very simple (and often still fast enough) way to get a function for 2x2 matrices to work for 2x2xn matries.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how I can use `bsxfun` with a function that has only one matrix argument. I can't find a way to use `arrayfun` either. The only thing I could think of was using a cell array of matrices and use `cellfun`.

Comment: @Pincopallino `bsxfun` has the syntax - `bsxfun(function_name,matrix1,,matrix2)`. Thus, if your operation is say performing `summing`, use `sum` as `function_name` there. On `arrayfun` and `cellfun`, it appears they use loops internally, so you are better off using `for-loops` than looking into `cellfun` or `arrayfun`, if performance is your primary objective. To summarize on your issue in general - No there isn't a ready-made formula or format or directive in MATLAB to vectorize codes, but in very data independent and no-conditional cases you can look into `parfor` that uses P-MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have preallocated your `p`, I doubt that you can get much of a speedup in any way. Here is how you can make sure the `p` does not grow every step of the way:

```
for i = size(rho,3):-1:1
   p(i) = real(trace(rho(:,:,i)^2));
end
```

Make sure to run a benchmark test, but I would be surprised if this matlab code turned out to be slower than the mathematica equivalent.

Comment: I didn't paste the line of code, but I preallocate the `p` variable.